# Instantiate objects within the terrain area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 terrainArea;
    public float spinSpeed = 2.0f;
    public int cloneTeleportations;
    public GameObject prefab;

    private bool rotate = false;
    private bool exited = false;
    private Transform[] teleportations;
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    private void Start()
    {

        GameObject go = GameObject.Find("Terrain");            
        Terrain terrain = go.GetComponent(Terrain);
        terrainArea = terrain.terrainData.size;

        for (int i = 0; i < cloneTeleportations; i++)
        {
            GameObject Teleportaion = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(Random.Range(i * 10.0F, i * 50.0F), 0, Random.Range(i * 10.0F, i * 50.0F)), Quaternion.identity);
            Teleportaion.transform.parent = this.transform;
            Teleportaion.transform.tag = "Teleportation";
        }
    } 
}
```

Now some gameobjects are out of the terrain area.
What I want to do is to keep the clones to be in random position but only inside the terrain area.

How I do Instantiate Objects inside the terrain area?

Comment: I don't see a terrain area...

Comment: @MelO'Hagan right i updated my question with the terrain size part. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that you are creating new instance of the `Random` class. Don't do that with Unity's [`Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) API. Just use [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) to generate random numbers.

As for generating random GameObjects on a terrain:

***1***.Find the X position:

```
Min = terrain.terrainData.size.x.

Max = terrain.transform.position.x + terrain.terrainData.size.x.
```

The final random X should be:

```
randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(Min, Min + Max);
```

---

***2***.Find the Z position:

```
Min = terrain.transform.position.z;

Max = terrain.transform.position.z + terrain.terrainData.size.z;
```

The final random Z should be:

```
 randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(Min, Min + Max);
```

---

***3***.Find the Y position:

The y-axis does not have to be random. Although, you can make it a random value if you want.

It just has to be over the terrain so that the Instantiated Object will not be under the terrain.

This is where [`Terrain.SampleHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain.SampleHeight.html) comes into place. You **must** use this function in order to perfectly generate a position that is not under the terrain. You need the result from **#1** and **#2** to use this:

```
yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));
```

If you want to apply offset to the y-axis, you can now do it at this time.

```
yVal = yVal + yOffset;
```

---

Below is a general example. You have to use this example to extend your current code.

```
public GameObject prefab;
public Terrain terrain;
public float yOffset = 0.5f;

private float terrainWidth;
private float terrainLength;

private float xTerrainPos;
private float zTerrainPos;


void Start()
{
    //Get terrain size
    terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
    terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

    //Get terrain position
    xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
    zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

    generateObjectOnTerrain();
}

void generateObjectOnTerrain()
{
    //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
    float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
    float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
    float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

    //Apply Offset if needed
    yVal = yVal + yOffset;

    //Generate the Prefab on the generated position
    GameObject objInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Comment: Great and thorough answer. I had multiple terrains and activeTerrain was sampling the wrong one, which led to the y offset on the cloned objects appearing random. In case anyone else has that issue, make sure you're calling SampleHeight on the same terrain referenced for the random x/z