# Rotate GameObject based on key presses and based on Terrain slope/curvature

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics

I have code in C# in a game in Unity that needs to rotate the player based on the slope of the terrain but the RotateTowards function(calculates the slope and angle) doesn't allow the object to be rotated sideway to move it in different directions. If I take out the rotateTowards function, rotations sideways work. If I dont, the correct slope rotation works but player won'r rotate sideways when buttons are pressed.

How could I fix this so the player could rotate in both ways?

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class PlayerController1 : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [System.Serializable]
     public class MoveSettings
     {
         public float forwardVel = 10f;      // walk speed

         public float rotateVel = 100;       // character rotation speed, character can walk 360 degree

         public float jumpVel = 25f;
         public LayerMask ground;

         public Transform backLeft;   // back left feet
         public Transform backRight;  // back right feet
         public Transform frontLeft;  // front left feet 
         public Transform frontRight; // front left feet
     }

     [System.Serializable]
     public class PhysicsSettings
     {
         public float downAccel = 0.75f;     // down speed when not grounded
     }

     public GameObject Model;
      public GameObject Origin;
     public MoveSettings moveSettings = new MoveSettings();
     public PhysicsSettings physicsSettings = new PhysicsSettings();

     private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
     private Quaternion targetRotation;
     private CharacterController cc;

     private float forwardInput, turnInput, jumpInput = 0;

     private RaycastHit lr;
     private RaycastHit rr;
     private RaycastHit lf;
     private RaycastHit rf;
     private Vector3 upDir;

     private Animator Anim; // global private variable



     private void Start()

     {   
         Anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); // in the Start function
         targetRotation = transform.rotation;
         cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     }


     public bool Grounded()
     {
         return cc.isGrounded;
     }



     private void FixedUpdate()
     {

         Run();  // calculate the velocity to be applied on character controller, stored in the velocity variable
         Jump(); // code for jumping
          GetInput();     // movement input keys
         Turn();         // character movement direction input

         cc.Move(transform.TransformDirection(velocity) * Time.deltaTime);
         RotateTowardsGround();
     }

     private void GetInput()
     {

 Anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", forwardInput); // in the GetInput() function
 Anim.SetFloat("Direction", 1f);
         forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
         turnInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         jumpInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Jump");
     }

     private void Turn()
     {
         targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(moveSettings.rotateVel * turnInput * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
         transform.rotation = targetRotation;



     }

     public void Jump()
     {
         if (jumpInput > 0 && Grounded())
         {
             velocity.y = moveSettings.jumpVel;
         }
         else if (jumpInput == 0 && Grounded())
         {
             velocity.y = 0;
         }
         else
         {
             velocity.y -= physicsSettings.downAccel;
         }
     }

     private void Run()
     {

         velocity.z = moveSettings.forwardVel * forwardInput;
     }

         public void RotateTowardsGround()
     {

         // we have four feet

         Physics.Raycast(moveSettings.backLeft.position + Vector3.up, Vector3.down, out lr);
         Physics.Raycast(moveSettings.backRight.position + Vector3.up, Vector3.down, out rr);
         Physics.Raycast(moveSettings.frontLeft.position + Vector3.up, Vector3.down, out lf);
         Physics.Raycast(moveSettings.frontRight.position + Vector3.up, Vector3.down, out rf);
         upDir = (Vector3.Cross(rr.point - Vector3.up, lr.point - Vector3.up) +
                  Vector3.Cross(lr.point - Vector3.up, lf.point - Vector3.up) +
                  Vector3.Cross(lf.point - Vector3.up, rf.point - Vector3.up) +
                  Vector3.Cross(rf.point - Vector3.up, rr.point - Vector3.up)
                 ).normalized;
         Debug.DrawRay(rr.point, Vector3.up);
         Debug.DrawRay(lr.point, Vector3.up);
         Debug.DrawRay(lf.point, Vector3.up);
         Debug.DrawRay(rf.point, Vector3.up);



         Model.transform.up = upDir;

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to rotate object based on Terrain slope/curvature is to first throw raycast then obtain the returned [`RaycastHit.normal`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-normal.html) value and assign it your to the object's `transform.up`. It's better to use `Lerp` or `Slerp` to do this form smooth ration.

As for the position of the object, you can calculate that with `Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988991/instantiate-objects-within-the-terrain-area/43991639#43991639) post or you can use [`RaycastHit.point`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) like you did in the code from your question.

Below is an example of what I described above. It is a *minimal* code to move/rotate object over a terrain. You can modify it to fit your four character legs scenario.

```
public class Hover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objectToMove;
    public float maxSpeed = 10f;
    public float angleSpeed = 5f;
    public float groundDistOffset = 2f;
    private Vector3 toUpPos = Vector3.zero;

    void Update()
    {
        float hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 objPos = objectToMove.position;
        objPos += objectToMove.forward * vInput * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        objPos += objectToMove.right * hInput * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(objectToMove.position, -Vector3.up, out hit))
        {
            //Get y position
            objPos.y = (hit.point + Vector3.up * groundDistOffset).y;

            //Get rotation
            toUpPos = hit.normal;
        }

        //Assign position of the Object
        objectToMove.position = objPos;

        //Assign rotation/axis of the Object
        objectToMove.up = Vector3.Slerp(objectToMove.up, toUpPos, angleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great change to the code but it still doesn't allow me to rotate the player sideways based on the key input as it is always rotating with the terrain. This just lets me move it in all directions but not rotate

Comment: This is a long ago I made this and I still expect it to work. When I have time I will create a terrain and test it again to make sure this functioning properly.  Can you create a simple 3D capsule and this code to control it over a terrain. See if it rotates. Don't make any changes to it.

Comment: Yes I had tried this and the player can move in every direction and rotates based on the terrain, but instead of moving left when the left key is pressed, I need it to rotate left which the slope rotation doesn't allow

Comment: I think that I don't understand the issue. Can you put up an animated gif or video that shows the described problem? That would be helpful.

Comment: Video - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0DLxcSN2i96M1hNZ19YLWYtUFU       Player moves in all directions but horizontal keys don't rotate the player in either direction, they just move it.

Comment: Oh lol I see what you are talking. That's some funny stuff. I will update my answer in few minutes. Let me sure, you just want it to rotate left/right when you press the left/right keys respectively?

Comment: Yeah do thanks and that so it wouldn't affect the slope rotation when rotating

Comment: That's a bit more like what I am looking for though I think something is off as it keeps stuttering and sometimes the rotation isn't right on the slope    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0DLxcSN2i96TjEyWTBvdUJCTms

Comment: Not on my computer to test and see what's the cause of the stuttering. I will reply back when I am on my computer.